# Is there a way to disable symbolic links for nginx auto-indexed directory?

Tags: linux, security, nginx, symbolic-link

I would like to configure nginx to list and serve bulk files from a select directory (autoindex on option). However I worry that if a symbolic link will be accidentally placed in such a directory,  all files in the filesystem may become externally exposed (for example by a symbolic link to /).

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`disable_symlinks`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) directive:

```
disable_symlinks on
```

Comment: note that this parameter is only available from 1.1.16.